# Iterate over rows and select all between max and min

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

Suppose I have a Pandas DataFrame like the following:

```
ID  update_time     cap date      diff
A   05/05/21 1:45   136 05/05/21    136
A   05/05/21 1:50   0   05/05/21    -136
A   05/05/21 2:10   1   05/05/21    1
A   05/05/21 2:15   0   05/05/21    -1
A   05/05/21 3:35   1   05/05/21    1
A   05/05/21 3:40   0   05/05/21    -1
A   05/05/21 14:40  158 06/05/21    158
A   05/05/21 14:45  0   06/05/21    -158
A   05/05/21 15:10  1   06/05/21    1
A   07/05/21 9:49   0   07/05/21    -1
B   05/05/21 1:10   500 05/05/21    500
B   05/05/21 1:15   63  05/05/21    -437
B   05/05/21 1:20   0   05/05/21    -63
B   05/05/21 1:35   8   05/05/21    8
B   05/05/21 1:40   0   05/05/21    -8
B   05/05/21 1:45   3   05/05/21    3
B   05/05/21 1:50   0   05/05/21    -3
B   05/05/21 14:35  255 06/05/21    255
B   05/05/21 14:40  0   06/05/21    -255
```

I want to drop any `cap` values that occur after the first drop to 0 within each ID and date. Any pointers on how I can achieve this? I have attached the expected output below.

```
ID  update_time     cap date      diff
A   05/05/21 1:45   136 05/05/21    136
A   05/05/21 1:50   0   05/05/21    -136
A   05/05/21 14:40  158 06/05/21    158
A   05/05/21 14:45  0   06/05/21    -158
B   05/05/21 1:10   500 05/05/21    500
B   05/05/21 1:15   63  05/05/21    -437
B   05/05/21 1:20   0   05/05/21    -63
B   05/05/21 14:35  255 06/05/21    255
B   05/05/21 14:40  0   06/05/21    -255
```

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: What does "after they initially drop to 0" mean? How come the "A, 158" exists row if we are excluding everything after 0, why not consider "A, 1" rows?

Comment: A, 158 is selected, because the value in the "date" column changes.

Comment: @thinrhino that's an important detail that I would recommend you add into your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first perform a `groupby` on the `ID` and `date` since you want `"all rows before a drop to 0 occurs in caps"` for each unique ID-date combination. Then we will apply a custom function that selects all rows before the occurrence of the first zero. The function takes into account the edge case that no "drop to 0" can occur for an ID-date that only occurs once.

Note that I only used the relevant portion of your DataFrame.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

## recreate the relevant portion of your DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':['A']*10+['B']*9,
    'cap':[136,0,1,0,1,0,158,0,1,0,500,63,0,8,0,3,0,255,0],
    'date':['05/05/21']*6+['06/05/21']*3+['07/05/21']+['05/05/21']*7+['06/05/21']*2
})

## get the caps values before the first occurrence of a zero 
def get_caps_before_zero(df_column):
    ## for an ID-cap groupby of length 1, no "drop" to zero can occur, so return an empty DataFrame
    if len(df_column) == 1:
        return df_column.iloc[0:0]
    else:
        idx_first_zero = np.where(df_column == 0)[0].min() + 1
        return df_column.iloc[:idx_first_zero]

df_subset = (df.groupby(['ID','date'])
    .apply(lambda x: get_caps_before_zero(x['cap']))
    .reset_index()
    .drop(columns='level_2')
)
```

Output:

```
>>> df_subset
  ID      date  cap
0  A  05/05/21  136
1  A  05/05/21    0
2  A  06/05/21  158
3  A  06/05/21    0
4  B  05/05/21  500
5  B  05/05/21   63
6  B  05/05/21    0
7  B  06/05/21  255
8  B  06/05/21    0
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Learnt a few new things about pandas.

Comment: No problem, glad my solution was helpful!